# Bootstrap 4 cards - Make first cards bigger

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

I am building a website where the home is a collection of cards, all wrapped in the .card-columns class (they look like a Masonry layout now).

I would like to keep the masonry style, but instead of having all the cards the same width (right now there are 6 columns on large screens), I would like the first card to use 3 or those 6 columns (col-lg-6 maybe?) and the second to use 2 columns. The others will follow and they will all be the same size.

As the content evolves, I would like to write the code once (so no one-shot classes).

Thank you

Here's my code:

```
<div class="card-columns">

    <a class="card" href="">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="...">
        <div class="card-body border-web">              
           <p>Some content</p>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a class="card" href="">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="...">
        <div class="card-body border-web">              
           <p>Some content</p>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a class="card" href="">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="...">
        <div class="card-body border-web">              
           <p>Some content</p>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: I cannot see how it could be done using BS or even just plain CSS.

There are a few problems with using Bootstrap for this

- `card-columns` use css columns
- `cards` in columns cannot cross column boundaries

If you use `card-group` where `card` widths can be managed but then:

- you lose the Masonry like effect of `card-columns`

If you use the Bootstrap Grid system (col-1 etc...) you get:

- the ability to adjust column widths and the columns will wrap
- but again you lose the Masonry effect of staggered "cells" being stacked properly

If you examine the [Masonry home page](https://masonry.desandro.com/) you will see a LOT of absolute positioning due to the css options being so strictly defined.

Using BS this is as close as I could get with a few overrides and 2 custom sizing classes.

I'm using `card-group` to get the flex options and then overriding some CSS definitions (not a good idea)...still not bad.  Also margins mess up the layout so you would need to add more wrappers internal to the `card` to handle borders and margins without breaking flex flow.

And as content is added you may need to move the spacing classes `.x2` and `.x3` to other cards so this is not a "fire and forget" solution.  In fact it's no solution at all for what you're trying to accomplish.  This is more to show you the reason Masonry exists.

```css
/* redefines the flex "columns" to 4 per row
*/

.card-group>.card {
  flex: 0 1 25% !important;
  border-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px) !important;
}


/* span 3 "columns"
*/

.x3 {
  min-width: 75% !important;
}


/* span 2 "columns"
*/

.x2 {
  min-width: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card-group">
    <div class="card x3 p-3">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/100/80" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card p-3">
      <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0 card-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
        <footer class="blockquote-footer">
          <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card x2">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/100/80" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-primary text-white text-center p-3">
      <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
        <footer class="blockquote-footer">
          <small>
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card text-center">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/80" alt="Card image">
    </div>
    <div class="card p-3 text-right">
      <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
        <footer class="blockquote-footer">
          <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```